# What is a post_form_id? (using python urllib2)

Tags: python, facebook, authentication, urllib2

I'm interested in writing a python script to log into Facebook and then request some data (mainly checking the inbox). There are few nice examples out there on how to do this. One interesting script i found [over here](http://ruel.me/blog/2011/03/03/scrape-your-facebook-friends-emails-with-python/) and there is some nice example [on stackoverflow itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030652/logging-into-facebook-with-python).
Now i could just copy-paste some of the code i need and get to do what i want, but that wouldn't be a good way to learn. So i am trying to understand what i am actually coding and can't understand some elements of the script in the first example, namely: what is a **post_form_id**?

Here is the section of the code which refers to "post_form_id" (line 56-72):

```
# Initialize the cookies and get the post_form_data
print 'Initializing..'
res = browser.open('http://m.facebook.com/index.php')
mxt = re.search('name="post_form_id" value="(\w+)"', res.read())
pfi = mxt.group(1)
print 'Using PFI: %s' % pfi
res.close()

# Initialize the POST data
data = urllib.urlencode({
    'lsd'               : '',
    'post_form_id'      : pfi,
    'charset_test'      : urllib.unquote_plus('%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E6%B0%B4%2C%D0%94%2C%D0%84'),
    'email'             : user,
    'pass'              : passw,
    'login'             : 'Login'
})
```

Would you be so kind to tell me what a **post_form_id** is? And accessorily: would you know what the **lsd** key/value stands for?

Thanks.

Comment: ]its a variable facebook uses for something...they search for the value on the index.php page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are trying to "hack" this ... 
There is an official api from facebook to read the mailbox of a user, and you need to ask the "read_mailbox" permission for this.

So I advice you to check [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730545/how-to-redirect-the-url-after-logging-into-facebook/5731508#5731508) on how to use facebook and python/django together, and how to login to facebook from python.

And then I would recommend you to read the [facebook doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/) about the messages/inbox.

Basically you need an access_token then you can do `http://graph.facebook.com/me/inbox/?access_token=XXX`
You can also ask for the "offline_access" permission so you'll need only to get an access token once and you will be able to use it "forever"

And the you can do `http://graph.facebook.com/MESSAGE_ID?access_token=XXX` to get the details about a particular message.

Or using the api I use in the other thread :

```
f = Facebook() 
res = f.get_object("me/inbox")
...
```

Feel free to comment if you have any question about this ?

Comment: Thanks Dwarfy,
Two things:
* first i took a look at the official Facbook API and found i needed to register a new application. When doing so, Facebook asked me to identify myself with my credit-card, which i found suspicious. I asked myself: what does my credit-card have to do with a free and open-source application that anyone can use and modify? And if my browser can read Facebook without my credit-card then why do i need one when checking the code?
* second: i want to learn about Python, this is a good practice for me and this is why i asked the question.
I will look at your post. Thanks

Comment: Yep I can understand your fear about the credit card stuff ... But I think you can also identify yourself using a mobile phone ... I think Facebook is doing it in order to prevent abuse from developers

Comment: True. But the country i reside is --the Netherlands-- is not listed... Besides, if my app id is in the (open-source) code, then anyone can potentially use this code in my name... Anyhow, if you have any explanations on my original question, regarding the post_form_id, i'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Yep Sorry About Facebook politics. I cannot help you on the 'post_form_id' stuff ... and about opensource code it's common practice to remove this kind of info (I mean passwords, ids, and secrets) before opensourcing ..

Comment: Dwarfy, you say "it is common practice to remove this kind of info". I don't grasp that: shouldn't the App ID, API key and Secret etc. be **included** into the code? If not so then how?

Comment: Hi Benjamin, I mean you just manually remove it from the source code before putting it on a public repository and sharing it with everybody. You put placeholders and explain in your documentation : place your APP ID here, place your API KEY here ...

Comment: Ha i see, so that would mean each user has to get his/her own App ID? That's a bit odd: then username and password would have sufficed. But you're right. Why not. Thanks

Comment: Yep I'm not sure we are talking about the same thing here, The users of your application DO NOT SEE your app secret (your app id is public anyway) when they use it so there is no problem about this.. I was talking in the case where you want to opensource the code of your application for other developers to use it and ameliorate it..

Comment: Well if i write a code in Python, anyone can see the code right? And the key/pass is **in** the code right? Or am i confused?

Comment: So in web applications they are two parts : the server side and the client side. The server code is NOT visible to the user . The client code is visible to the user. (For example if your developing a python/django app you have python code that produces HTML+CSS+Javascript and send that to the browser of the user. The python code is NOT visible by the client only what it outputs (the webpage).

Comment: I see. I do this for an applet appending a dock. I have to keep it simple and local. So i may let each user register their own instance of the applet if they want to use it rather than an applet based on FBCMD. Thanks for the tips! :)