# programmatically update facebook status

Tags: python, facebook, post, status

Is there a Python program where you can post a status update without going to the website itself?

Where or how do i get started?

Comment: Try to start with reading http://developers.facebook.com

Comment: did it work? Im trying to do the same program and I'm wandering were to start? when I use import facebook its giving module not available! any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would wanna get started here, https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk

unless there's a library I don't know about.

Comment: Also, If you finish this. I'd like to see it. I've thought about doing it myself. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout [my fork of the python sdk](https://bitbucket.org/dwarfy/my-facebook-py/src). It's customized to work better with django.
You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730545/how-to-redirect-the-url-after-logging-into-facebook/5731508#5731508) on how to use it to authenticate a user.

After that you can use the python sdk to post a news entry.

```
 fb.put_wall_post("hello")
```

Or do it yourself, it's only a matter of doing a POST request to http://graph.facebook.com/FBID/feed where FBID is the ID of the page or profile you want to publish to, [more info in the facebook doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing).